# NumberFormatException; Empty String, double.parseDouble

Tags: java, spring-boot, github, double

Trying to get Covid Data from raw Github data but running into an issue with empty String being returned. Trying to work around it but running into some issues. Was trying to display via the current parameters and replacing the double data type with int and parsing it to string but could not figure it out.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;



import io.javabrains.coronavirustracker.models.copy.LocationStats;



@Service
public class CoronaVirusDataService {

    
            public static String VIRUS_DATA_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/04-16-2021.csv";
            
            
            private List<LocationStats> allStats = new ArrayList<>();
            
            @PostConstruct
            @Scheduled(cron = "* * 1 * * *")
            public void fetchVirusData() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                List<LocationStats> newStats = new ArrayList<>();

                HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
                HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(VIRUS_DATA_URL))
                .build();
        
        HttpResponse<String> httpResponse = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        StringReader csvBodyReader = new StringReader(httpResponse.body());
        
            
            
            
        
            Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(csvBodyReader);
            for (CSVRecord record : records) {
                LocationStats locationStat = new LocationStats();
                locationStat.setState(record.get("Province_State"));
                locationStat.setCountry(record.get("Country_Region"));
             
                locationStat.setLatestTotalCases(Double.parseDouble(record.get(record.size()- 1)));
                
                System.out.println(locationStat);
                
                newStats.add(locationStat);
            }
            this.allStats = newStats;
            }
    
    
    
}
```

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class CoronavirusTrackerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CoronavirusTrackerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

````
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'coronaVirusDataService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at io.javabrains.coronavirustracker.CoronavirusTrackerApplication.main(CoronavirusTrackerApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549) ~[na:na]
    at io.javabrains.coronavirustracker.CoronaVirusDataService.fetchVirusData(CoronaVirusDataService.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check your CSVRecord `records` object. Is your record object getting populated properly? Check your `for` loop as well.

Comment: can you update your code with this pojo class. io.javabrains.coronavirustracker.models.copy.LocationStats

Comment: @MuhammadTariq I've tried that and am receiving the first portion of results until I get to a certain point in the raw data that contains an empty string.

Comment: @Ranjan14 the Pojo class already exists in my service layer. need to work around the empty string.

Comment: If you know that there is an empty string , the you can handle it via putting the check for empty string. Is that empty string in the `records` object? Do you know how to handle empty object ?